Flutter excel package cannot read Excel file created in Go with Excelize
I have an Excel file generated with the Excelize package in Go. I also have a Flutter app that tries to read this Excel file using the excel package.
This fails during encoding in the line below
var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

I get the following error:

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)

When I open the same Excel file using Microsoft Excel and save, then try to open it again with the Flutter excel package, it works.
Can someone help explain and if possibly provide a solution?

.xlsx is a pretty complex format and there are multiple ways of saving the same sheet. When you load/save in Excel it will write the file differently to Excelize (likely that neither is "incorrect"). It appears you have found a bug in your flutter excel library (please confirm library and version); this may be due to Excelize doing something unexpected (but not necessarily wrong). It's difficult to help without more info (e.g. ideally MRE but, at minimum, full error with stack trace).

I am getting the same issue! Here, I am trying to read the generated excel with python using pandas and I am getting the following error
ValueError: Unable to read workbook: could not read stylesheet from ./excelize_generated.xlsx. This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML. Please see the exception for more details.
When I open file manually using excel it works, when I save file and retry pandas works... It's a bit of strange cause when I save file again, I can notice file size is changing from 4Mb to 2Mb...
